# How to display a "bootstrap" dashboard in html page ?

Tags: html, dashboard

Use scenario:
 An independent bootstrap-dashboard is created using an independent tools, like Grafana or ELK. Now I want to host this dashboard in a html (frame?).

Currently, I have a bootstrap dashboard created by Grafana. With IIS, I can display the dashboard by http://localhost/dashboard/Grafana_dashboard/index.htm.  The question is how to display this dashboard in a webpage, assuming the http server is configured appropriately.

Comment: By... uploading it to the webserver, make sure that all dependencies are met (like paths and CSS-files and javascript)? It doesn't care (well, shouldn't care) what the folders are called, or even what the actual html-file is called, as long as you modify whatever paths and links accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The challenge part is how to view the dashboard without leaving the html, which "framed" the dashboard.

Comment: As I have no idea how Grafana works, but normally, to have a dashboard, you will need some sort of server-part to manage whatever you're using the dashboard for. But apart from that, I'm not sure I understand the problem. What do you mean "leaving the HTML"? Are you talking about having the dashboard be "part of" the rest of the site? (Same header and footer, same color scheme etc)?